# Why am i getting a csrf error in my POST form? (django/python)

Tags: python, django

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
def home(request):  
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username", '') 
        password = request.POST.get("password", '') 
        return render_to_response("login_home.html", {"username":username, "password":password})
    else:
        return render_to_response("login_home.html")
```

## login_home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block page %}
    {{ name }}
    <form action = "/blog/home/" method = "POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type = "text" name = "username" placeholder = "username">
    <input type = "text" name = "password" placeholder = "password">
    <input type = "submit">
    </form>

    {{ username }}
    {{ password }}

{% endblock %}
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^home/$', 'blog.views.home'),
)
```

^^Here are my files. The problem is the error i get once i submit the form:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

I am not exactly sure what i am forgetting or missing. I am guessing its somewhere in the views function. Can someone point put the bit i am missing?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use a `RequestContext` or return the context you have created with `c.update(csrf(request))`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

> 1. Use RequestContext, which always uses 'django.core.context_processors.csrf' (no matter what your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting). If you are using generic views or contrib apps, you are covered already, since these apps use RequestContext throughout.
> 2. Manually import and use the processor to generate the CSRF token and add it to the template context. e.g....

```
return render_to_response("login_home.html",
    {"username":username, "password":password}
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What should i change my code to then?

Comment: I've showed you; add a `RequestContext` to you `render_to_response` method